# Guardar Imagenes de Base64 a PNG en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, base64

Estoy guardando imágenes en Base64, pero no selecciona de la tabla product_img para guardar en la tabla product_imagenes (donde se guardan ya en png)

Asi esta mi codigo actualmente

```
<?php
require('mysqli.php'); // conexion de db
$qMain = ExecuteReader("SELECT * FROM product_img;"); // consulta a la tabla product_img
foreach($qMain['data'] as $r) { // recorremos cada lina 
$art_codigo = $r->art_codigo; // seleccionamos el art_codigo
$imagenes = $r->imagen;    // seleccionamos la imagen
$imagenEnBase64 =  $imagenes;   // variable de imagen en b64
$filename = $art_codigo.'.png'; // declaramos el nombre de la imagen segun el art_codigo
$rutaImagenSalida = __DIR__ . '/'.$filename.''; // difinimos la ruta donde se va a cargar la imagen
$imagenBinaria = base64_decode($imagenEnBase64); // decodificamos la imagen en b64
$bytes = file_put_contents($rutaImagenSalida, $imagenBinaria); // subimos la imagen


// llego el momento de insertar la imagen en la base de datos
ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO product_imagenes (art_codigo, imagenes) VALUES ('*?*', '*?*');", array(
        $r->art_codigo,
        $rutaImagenSalida
        ));

// eliminamos de la talba product_img el articulo
            ExecuteNonQuery("DELETE FROM product_img WHERE art_codigo = *?*;", array(
                $r->art_codigo
            ));

    }
};

// una vez terminado mostramos el siguiente mensaje 
echo "<pre>";
echo '{

     "Response": "Registros Actualizados Con Exito"

}';
?>
```

Alguna sugerencia para mejorar el codigo, para no tener inconvenientes ?

Gracias

Comment: No entiendo, ¿qué tipo de datos son tus columnas `product_img.imagen` y `product_imagenes.imagenes`?

Comment: ¿Algo más, tu intención es guardar la ruta de la imagen en la tabla `product_imagenes`?, ¿o por el contrario intentas guardar el contenido de la misma, sea en binario o en `varchar`?